# How to determine if crypto acceleration is available?

Tags: android, cryptography, android-keystore

The usage of a hardware-backed keystore on Android is slow unless the hardware keystore is accelerated (like in Samsung's S8). There is [an Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.html#isInsideSecureHardware()) to detect whether or not a `Key` is stored in secure hardware or not when it is put into the Android `KeyStore` from API level 23 onwards, but I miss an API to detect if the keystore is hardware-accelerated. Is there such a thing?

Rationale: If the user has a (fast) software keystore or an accelerated hardware-backed one, one could hint the user to pick a greater key length (e.g. 4096 for RSA keys), while on non-accelerated, slow hardware-backed keystores a smaller key size would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) for Android 8.1](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd) is for the [Fingerprint Sensor [C-1-6]](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd#7_3_10_fingerprint_sensor)  to 'MUST' have a [Trusted Execution Environment (TEE)](https://source.android.com/security/trusty/)

Other references in the CDD to [Keys and Credentials](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd#9_11_keys_and_credentials) implies that a hardware backed secure element exists, but doesn't necessarily mean that crypto performance is hardware accelerated.

Note that in an earlier [Android CDD 6.0 - Keys and Credentials](https://source.android.com/compatibility/6.0/android-6.0-cdd#9_11_keys_and_credentials) the TEE was highly suggested unless there was a Fingerprint Sensor.

Note that I'm not sure for your specific use case of long key length creation maps to secure storage features as features such as full disk encryption appear to use predefined key length.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info, I thought as much. My use case is that I need to decrypt the individual AES secret for a list of items with an RSA private key and saw major performance hit when this RSA key was linked to a hardware-backed AndroidKeystore. In this case, low-end devices with no such hardware-backed keystore (but a software-only solution) outperformed mid-end devices that had a hardware-backed keystore, but no crypto acceleration up to factor **10x**.